# Confused about SELECT and JOIN command in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, Courses and Faculties.

- Courses has columns: ID(primary key), description, level,
  instructor_id(foreign key), and semester.
- Faculties has columns: faculty_id(primary key), name, date_of_birth,
  address, email, and level.

instructor_id in Courses references faculty_id in Faculties.

I'm trying to write a query that lists all the courses taught by a certain instructor, given the instructor's name. How would I go about doing this? I'm very new to SQL in general. I understand it might have something to do with JOINs?

So far I have this, which is wrong, but I don't where to go from here.

```
SELECT "Courses".description, "Courses".semester, "Faculties".name 
FROM "Courses" 
INNER JOIN "Faculties" ON "Courses".instructor = "Faculties".faculty_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `where` clause to find the courses taught by the given `instructor's name`.

```
SELECT "Courses".description,
       "Courses".semester,
       "Faculties".name
FROM   "Courses"
       INNER JOIN "Faculties"
               ON "Courses".instructor_id = "Faculties".faculty_id
WHERE  Faculties.name = 'Given Name';
```